# ng-repeat on select box flashing options after selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have used ng-repeat in select box, it showing all options, once i select any option then all the options get flash, not able to understand why these happening

```
<select name="medical_specialty" ng-model="medical_specialty" class="form-control" ng-if="medical_specialty">
          <option value="">All Specialties</option>
        <option ng-repeat ="medical_s in medical_specialty track by $index" value="{{medical_s.id}}">{{medical_s.name}}</option>
        </select>
```

**Front view at first load, I am not able to understand why `? object:300 ?`**

[image]

**After selection of any option all option get flash**

[image]

Comment: Why do you have  ng-if="medical_specialty"?

Comment: it just to check value

Comment: Can remove and see of flashing is there?

Comment: result is same first whole list loaded and after selection all options get flashed

Comment: Are you doing anything on change of medical_specialty?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ng-options` for showing the options in the select rather than an ng-repeat for the `<option>` tag.

An example for ng-options would be

```
 <select ng-options="user.name for user in users track by user.id" ng-model="selectedUser"></select>
```

In your case, try

```
 <select name="medical_specialty" ng-model="medicalSpecialty" ng-options=""medical_s.name for medical_s in medical_specialty track by $index">
```

> Read more about `ng-options` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)
>
> ```js
> angular.module('Demo', []).controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope) {
>   $scope.users = [{
>     id: 1,
>     name: 'John'
>   }, {
>     id: 2,
>     name: 'Doe'
>   }];
> });
> ```
>
> ```html
> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
>
> <body ng-app="Demo">
>   <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
>     <select ng-options="user.name for user in users track by user.id" ng-model="selectedUser"></select>
>
>     <div>
>       Selected User: {{selectedUser}}
>     </div>
>   </div>
> </body>
> ```